# find(), each() and replacewith() in passed HTML in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, replace, find

I have some HTML code that i'm passing to a function which is mean't to find all iframes, replace the iframe code with an image and then return the modified html. However, it doesn't seem to replace the iframe code in the returned html. I'm pretty sure im just referencing hte replacement wrongly, but can't find any examples online similar to what im trying to do. They all reference searching the whole of a document or after the html is displayed in the document. This HTML isn't and can't be due to application requirements.

**Please Note: I have already generated youtube code to replace the iframe code. The problem is with performing the replace.**

```
function article_youtube_convert(html) {
    //go throught the iframes for youtube and convert them to embed

    $(html).find('iframe').each(function(i) {
                     alert(this.src);
        //ok what we need to do here is check if it's youtube 
        src_youtube = this.src;
        if(src_youtube.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com')!=-1){
           //so now we need the video id 
           url_parts = src_youtube.split('/');

           youtube_id = url_parts[url_parts.length-1];

           url_parts = youtube_id.split('?');
           youtube_id = url_parts[0];

           youtube_link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+youtube_id;
           img_youtube = '<a id="tempvid" href="'+youtube_link+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+youtube_id+'/0.jpg"/><br />View YouTube Video</a>';

            $(this).replaceWith(img_youtube);


                     //alert(document.getElementById('tempvid').innerHTML);  
        }
    });
    return html;


}
```

UPDATE

I have decided to try using an outerHTML approach and replace the text with the new replacement text in the variable as per below. I alert the full source without a problem, but it still doesn't replace it.

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
    ? this.before(s).remove()
    : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};


function article_youtube_convert(passed) {
    //go throught the iframes for youtube and convert them to embed
    //alert('inside');
    newhtml = passed;
    //alert(newhtml);
    $(newhtml).find('iframe').each(function(i) {
                     //alert(this.src);
        //ok what we need to do here is check if it's youtube 
        src_youtube = this.src;
        if(src_youtube.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com')!=-1){
           //so now we need the video id 
           url_parts = src_youtube.split('/');
                                   alert('youtube vid');
           youtube_id = url_parts[url_parts.length-1];

           url_parts = youtube_id.split('?');
           youtube_id = url_parts[0];

           youtube_link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+youtube_id;
           img_youtube = '<a id="tempvid" href="'+youtube_link+'"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+youtube_id+'/0.jpg"/><br />View YouTube Video</a>';
                                   alert('alert: '+$(this).outerHTML());
                                   sourcethe = $(this).outerHTML();
                                   passed.replace(sourcethe,img_youtube);
            //$(this).replaceWith(img_youtube);
                                   //alert($(this));


                     //alert(document.getElementById('tempvid').innerHTML);  
        }
    });
    alert(passed);
    return passed;


}
```

Comment: did you check replaceWith can accept an HTML string ? I'd suggest trying replaceWith( $(img_youtube) ) and see what's the outcome.

Comment: @BiAiB: it saves time if you check the API yourself before saying that kind of thing. ;-) http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ suggests it can happily take a jquery object, html string or dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not actually returning what you want from that function...

You never actually alter `html` in your method, you just use it to do some stuff that gets discarded and then return what you put in.

What you most likely want to do is something like

```
var jqHtml = $(html);
...Do stuff to modify jqHtml...
return jqHtml.html();
```

One thing I am not sure on and haven't tested is whether .html() returns what you want. The docs say it uses the elements `innerHTML` property but I'm not sure if that will give the correct thing with jquery objects constructed from strings (I think it should).

Anyway, that is your basic problem, you are not modifying html at all. `$(html)` is taking a copy of the `html` string, not a reference to it that it can update as needed.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. Ok, well, in that case, i need something that will replace the iframe code in the html string with the code I have generated. The funny thing is, when i alert the src of the iframe it returns the correct stuff. So some of this stuff does work.

Comment: the alert at the beginning would work. Probably it all would work. The issue is that all the work you are doing is on `$(html)`. You are chaining everything to act on this but its not actually accessible after that becasue it isn't assigned to anything.and the `html` you are returning has nothing to do with the `$(html)` you have been working on. Try just putting $(html) into a variable before you work on it and then checking the .html() of that variable afterwards. Or just adding to the chaining but less chaining makes debugging easier. :)

Comment: Either it's not working, or im really stupid (more likely). I've tried assigning $(html) = html, i've even changed the sames to keep them seperate. It still won't replace.

Answer (score 1):

David, I just made a quick test and wrote a simple HTML page with three `iframe` elements and copied your code. I wrapped the iframes in a `<div id="test">` element and called `article_youtube_convert ("div#test");`. The iframes got replaced flawlessly.

```
<div id="test">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Z5y-UIjhjuM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Z5y-UIjhjuM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Z5y-UIjhjuM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Are you sure you're passing the right html context to the `article_youtube_convert` function?

Comment: I believe from the name of the paramater and the question that its not a selector that is being passed in but an HTML string. I outlined in my answer why I think that is causing it to go wrong. What you've got would certainly be a better way to do it though ratehr than passing in an HTML element as string. Of course I might have got that bit wrong. :)

Comment: @Chris, you're right! It's HTML code that gets passed to the function, not a selector. I must've overlooked that. Your answer seems to be correct, it's the modified HTML that should be returned. David's function, as it is, returns unmodified, inputed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
  url_parts = youtube_id.split('?');
  youtube_id = url_parts.pop();
```

But note that the `youtube_id` will include the `v=`, so you could do: `url_parts.pop().substring(2)`

Comment: The problem im having isn't with the youtube code, it's with replacing the html in jquery. I already have generated the replacement html.

Comment: @David Ok, my mistake. What happens when you do a `console.log(img_youtube)`, does it output as expected. If so, try `$(img_youtube).appendTo(document.body)` to see if anything happens

Comment: I don't want to stick it on the body, i merely want to swap the iframe html in the 'html' var with the generated replacement code.

Comment: @David yes, my suggestion was a debugging step. See if that works